# Logging objects and backslashes

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I just tracked down this very confusing `\\` issue I am having.

Here I'm assembling an object, which has one property which is a stringified object.

```
const status = 'alive'
const example = {status, name: 'Thomas', age: '28', home: 'Brooklyn'}
const dumbDecision = `{"status": "alive"}`
const str = JSON.stringify({dumbDecision, ...example})
console.log(str)
console.log({str})
```

When I log the `str` It has one set of slashes.

```
{"dumbDecision":"{\"status\": \"alive\"}","status":"alive","name":"Thomas","age":"28","home":"Brooklyn"}
```

However when I log the same object within another, it has double slashes.

```
{ str: '{"dumbDecision":"{\\"status\\": \\"alive\\"}","status":"alive","name":"Thomas","age":"28","home":"Brooklyn"}' }
```

What is going on here? Why are these slashes appearing when they are not necessary?

Comment: dumbDecision is already a string and `JSON.stringify `is escaping the backslash character, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

If this can help, "**\**" represent a character escape. When it happen most of the time it's because you try to stringify an already stringifyed string.

Hope it helped !

Edit :

```
const dumbDecision = `{"status": "alive"}`
```

this is a stringifyed string

```
const dumbDecision = {"status": "alive"}
```

this is an object. Removed the "**`**"

Answer (score 0):

you are nesting objects and strings within each other unnecessarily. you put the `const dumbDecision = {"status": "alive"}` within backticks, so it is already a String. Then when you Stringify this string into another string, the interpreter escapes the quotes.

Depending on what you are trying to do, i would keep the data in clean JSON objects. and not use stringify unless you need to for testing/debugging.